How do we handle questions on real-life events or lost media related to anime and manga?
Recently, a question cropped up that involves both topics, a real-life sweepstakes event that happened in the US, with any media related to it being essentially lost media.

This question will be very hard to answer due to the following reasons,

We cannot ascertain the accuracy of the details provided due to anything related to the event being lost media. The only valid sources of info are from past marketing staff, who may have left the company and are out of contact or don't remember much if they can even be contacted. The event likely happened over two to three decades ago.

Being a real-life event, such as a themed event, how on-topic would it have to be to be answerable? Questions about anime conventions and concerts might be on-topic, but where do we draw the line, if we even should?


Do we want to treat the aforementioned question as on-topic enough to be answered? Do we want to close it as being off-topic? Or do we want to migrate it to another community?
From here, I'd like to establish better guidelines for questions related to real-life events and how to handle lost media (as separate policies). Please leave your thoughts and suggestions as answers for them to be considered.

As a big of background, these television sweepstakes/contest did exist but likely were phased out due to broadcast laws on marketing towards children. The event described by the OP likely existed, but it might have been before a time where it could've been archived, this making it lost media.

Possibly related discussion about real-life events: Do we want questions about conventions?

This is certainly a niche topic, which is both a blessing and a curse: we could be the place where this niche topic is discussed that may attract people in the know to contribute to this site, but your first concern is also valid, it's next to impossible to verify the answers unless one is involved in said events.
I suggest we leave it open for now to see what kind of interesting or uninteresting questions we'll get and hopefully learn about some obscure/exclusive events that select anime and manga fans may partake in.
